# Algorithm for Making a Circle of Parity?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm trying to make a program (with a GUI) that will parse text file input, and create a "Circle of Parity", [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijw6G.jpg).

As a simple example, let's say Aaron, Bob, and Chuck are playing rock-paper-scissors, and:

- Aaron beats Bob
- Bob beats Chuck
- Chuck beats Aaron

Then, the circle of parity exists: Aaron > Bob > Chuck > Aaron (and repeats). By (illogical) inductive reasoning, one can say that Bob is better than Aaron at rock-paper-scissors, even though Bob lost to Aaron.

However, if:

- Aaron beats Bob
- Bob loses all matches
- Chuck beats Aaron

then no circle of parity exists. Each individual must have at least 1 win & 1 loss for a FULL circle of parity to exist. Because of this, it seems logical to me to start analyzing at a individual/team/node who has the fewest wins/losses.

Finally, if:

- Aaron beats Bob & Chuck
- Bob loses all matches
- Chuck beats Bob & Aaron

then an incomplete circle of parity exists: Aaron > Chuck > Aaron.

In my program, each team/individual will have a List of all the teams it has beaten, and the program will be dealing with a high number of teams (30+), so efficiency is always good. I can also implement a List of all the teams it lost to.  Any suggestions as to how to implement an algorithm to go through these lists?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack overflow is where you can ask coding questions - you have a particular problem with code, you paste it here, and developers will help you fix the issue. It isn't really a 'tell me how do I do xyz' such as the question you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem, for which there are no known efficient algorithms. For small graphs, backtracking search may be feasible. There is a dynamic programming solution which is theoretically faster than backtracking search - but this is just a change from about O(n!) to O(n^2*2^n)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, consider this...  (disclaimer: it is late, and I'm only brainstorming :-)  )

I'm struggling with the benefit of solving this with graph theory.

Suppose you did build a graph that captures every game.

How are you going to traverse it to generate scores?

You'll have to track a "visited" list for each players score, recursion city.

It seems like you'd have to do an exhaustive traversal for *each* player.

O(n^ouch)

So... tell me if this seems plausible:

```
Example Games:
A/B: winner.A
B/C: winner.B
C/A: winner.C

explicit (using vict since same # letters as loss):
A.vict.B   B.loss.A
B.vict.C   C.loss.B
C.vict.A   A.loss.C

Breaking all these out:
:   raw     : simple sort  :
: A.vict.B  : A.loss.C     :
: B.loss.A  : A.vict.B     :
: B.vict.C  : B.loss.A     :
: C.loss.B  : B.vict.C     :
: C.vict.A  : C.loss.B     :
: A.loss.C  : C.vict.A     :


Grouped by loss vs. vict:
A:  loss[ C ]   vict [ B ]
B:  loss[ A ]   vict [ C ]
C:  loss[ B ]   vict [ A ]
```

To rank your players...

What about starting with their net wins?

In the above example everybody has a zero net wins, so all are equally strong (or weak).

Or instead of net wins, maybe a winLossRatio for each player.  All players in the above example would have a ratio of 0.5  (e.g. 1 win / 2 total games).

Then generate a weightedWinLoss for the where you credit wins (and losses) by the opponent's strength.

This is probably better done as SQL updating a database table...

but a sketch of the idea follows in pseudo-java...

```
Class Player {
   //something to track all players.
   //and I suppose to load their wins & losses.
   static updateScores() {
      foreach player ( players ) {
         player.updateWinLossRatio();
      }
      // have to update ratios before computing scores using those ratios.
      foreach player ( players ) {
         player.updateWeightedScores();
      }
   }
   updateWinLossRatio() {
      // want #wins / totalGames
      winLossRatio = victories.size() / (victories.size() + losses.size() );
      // add check for zero and stuff.
   }
   updateWeightedScore() {
      weightedWinLoss = 0;
      foreach opponent ( victories ) {
         weightedWinLoss += opponent.winLossRatio;
         // this sort of already reduces credit for weak opponents,
         // since their win ratio would be pretty small.
      }
      foreach opponent ( losses ) {
         weightedWinLoss -= opponent.winLossRatio;
         // might want to penalize by inverse of opponents strength.
         // e.g. losing to a super weak opponent should hurt more.
         // so maybe:
         //    weightedWinLoss -= 1 / opponent.winLossRatio;
      }
   }
}
```

If I were doing this I'd want to run some formulas over my test data, plot the resulting curves and adjust it until it looked reasonable.  You may want to scale your scores, might look beter if the ratio is computed as log(wins)/log(totalgames) or what have you.